# Elasticsearch multitypes query with a script sorting strange behaviour

Tags: spring, sorting, elasticsearch

need your help to understand the behaviour of elasticsearch scripting based sorting.

First of all let me paste the mappings of my elasticsearch types :

```
{   
"nestedDateType" : {  
        "properties" : {
          "message" : {
            "properties" : {
              "date" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
              }
          }
        }
      }
  },
  "nonNestedDateType" : {
        "properties" : {
          "date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          }
        }
  }
}
```

now what I want to do is  to query these 2 types and sort based on the date.
The problem  is in nestedDateType, the date path is "message.date" where in nonNestedDateType, the date path is "date".

I understand that I have to use scripting based sort to do this. However, the script that I made did not work as expected. This is the query that I tried:

```
POST http://locahost:9200/index/nonNestedDateType,nestedDateType/_search?size=5000
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "or": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "date": {
                      "gte": "2015-04-01"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "message.date": {
                      "gte": "2015-04-01"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc.containsKey('message') ? doc.message.date.value : doc.date.value",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

and these were the result that I got :

```
{
  "took": 60,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 15,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "***",
        "_type": "nonNestedDateType",
        "_id": "***",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "docId": "***",
          "date": 1461634484557
        },
        "sort": [
          1461634484557
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "***",
        "_type": "nonNestedDateType",
        "_id": "***",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "docId": "***",
          "date": 1461634483528
        },
        "sort": [
          1461634483528
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "***",
        "_type": "nestedDateType",
        "_id": "***",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "docId": "***",
          "message": {
            "date": 1461548078310
          }
        },
        "sort": [
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

as you can see from the last result of the type nestedDateType, I was expecting the sort = 1461548078310 instead of 0. Could anyone explains to me what I was doing wrong?

noted that some fields have been removed for confidentiality.

Comment: Which ES version are your running?

Comment: I am using version 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

i can finally make it works by changing

```
script": "doc.containsKey('message') ? doc.message.date.value : doc.date.value"
```

into

```
script": "doc.date.value == 0 ? doc['message.date'].value : doc.date.value"
```

still curious though why doc.containsKey('message') never return true